# Faster way to convert large byte string to array of binary strings in Python

Tags: python, byte, bit

I'm looking for any tips on a faster/more efficient way to convert from a byte string to an array of binary strings.

The input data is a byte string packed as 32-bit integers in little endian. An example containing five 32-bit words in hex looks like this just for reference:

['0xfe6b2840', '0x0000c317', '0xc0008000', '0xb3e71e19', '0x16e40a6a']

But I need to operate on the bits of the 16-bit words. So I want to convert the input data to an array of 16-bit binary strings.

Here's my function so far that does the job but is slow when dealing with large input byte strings:

```
import numpy as np
def binarr(bytestr):
    ints = np.frombuffer(bytestr,dtype='<u4')  # data packed as 32-bit ints in little endian
    bins = list()
    for num in ints:
        bstr = bin(num)[2::].zfill(32)         # convert to 32-bit binary strings
        bins.append(bstr[0:16])                # split into two 16-bit binary strings
        bins.append(bstr[16::])
    return(np.array(bins))

data = b'@(k\xfe\x17\xc3\x00\x00\x00\x80\x00\xc0\x19\x1e\xe7\xb3j\n\xe4\x16'
bins = binarr(data)
```

The output of the code is this:

> ['1111111001101011', '0010100001000000', '0000000000000000',
> '1100001100010111', '1100000000000000', '1000000000000000',
> '1011001111100111', '0001111000011001', '0001011011100100',
> '0000101001101010']

```
timeit(binarr(data))
```

> 5.33 µs ± 116 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

I don't have lots of experience working with bytes and bits in Python so my main question is: is there any way to do this any faster (without of course going to C or Cython)?

I suspect the main slowdown here is just the Python loop and not so much `np.frombuffer` since that's probably highly optimized. But is there a more direct way to go from bytes to binary strings without first converting to ints? Or any other suggestions are appreciated.

Oh and I should mention that I've tried several other approaches like using `map(np.binary_repr,ints)` but so far everything else I've tried was slower than the function above.

Comment: Instead of squeezing a tiny bit of performance out of the conversion from integer to string it would be far more efficient to just drop the conversion entirely and operate on the integer's bits directly instead of operating on characters in a string representing that integer.

Comment: You're right! That's really the way to go I think. I've since updated my main code to operate bitwise on the integers rather than on the binary strings and it's a bit faster.